# Why is my Macbook Pro going to sleep while using it?

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake

2012 Macbook Pro 15" Non Retina
Randomly goes to sleep while I'm using it. Sometimes it resets altogether.
Its not a magnet, or Hot Corners
It takes 30-60 seconds to wake up.
The indicator light on the front lip stays solid for a long period and then fades on and off before I can wake it back up.

Comment: Does it still have the original battery? How's it doing?

Answer (score 1):

First thing to do is examine your power manager logs:

```
pmset -g log | grep "Entering Sleep"
```

When you find the timestamp(s) correlating to the unexpected sleep, please update your question with the full text of the relevant time range from `pmset -g log`.